# What to do if a position in css doesn't work to move an element?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I am trying to make the sub menu box full width of the screen but the menu size only increases from the right side the left side stays the same.

I tried adding `margin-right:50px !important;` nothing happened but if I do the same on the left side, the box moves.

I can't paste the full code here, so here is the link http://newlayouthomepage1.bluebirdpackaging.com/product/custom-cake-printed-boxes/
Click on Boxes By Industry to check the menu

Able to move the sub menu box on the left side

Comment: _"I can't past the full code here"_ - You don't need to. You should post all the _relevant_ code here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is this internal css that you have

```
.nav-menus #mega_main_menu > .menu_holder .menu_inner > ul > li.submenu_full_width > ul.mega_dropdown {
  width: 1450px;
}
```

Change this to

```
.nav-menus #mega_main_menu > .menu_holder .menu_inner > ul > li.submenu_full_width > ul.mega_dropdown {
  width: 100vw;
  margin-left: calc(590px - 50vw);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, Did you try it through inspect element ? If I am correct it's located in the index file not in the style.css file.

Comment: Yes, I absolutely love the inspect element tool of crome. 
internal css means the css in written within the `<style>` tag somewhere in index.html. If you inspect the element, you can see the style rule as well as the path of the css(top-right of the individual style box)

Comment: There is just small little problem,
"Pharma/Medicine Boxes" Doesn't show in one line. If you try {width:1450px;} it aligns it's self to a single line

Comment: Okay I managed to fix it with 
```    .nav-menus #mega_main_menu > .menu_holder .menu_inner > ul > li.multicolumn_dropdown > ul.mega_dropdown > li ul.mega_dropdown {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 204px;    ```
>sorry a pretty noob question but why isn't my code being indented I am using {} these before my code

Comment: So the system I am using has a screen width some 1330px. If width is set to 1450px, some part of the sub-menu gets hidden. I tried to make the width flexible(100vw takes 100% of the viewport-width). You can also try with `.mega_dropdown .item_link.with_icon{padding-right: 0 !important;}` in the index.html

Comment: :) use back-ticks to format your code in comment section (between ` `). I've also observed that indentation do not work in the comment section, it works good in the answer section.

Comment: Another try of posting the code properly  
`.nav-menus #mega_main_menu > .menu_holder .menu_inner > ul > li.multicolumn_dropdown > ul.mega_dropdown > li ul.mega_dropdown {
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    width: 204px;` 

Finally! Thanks guys for helping me start my stackflow journey :) Many more questions to come.

Comment: @sudipoto roy I am facing the issue again, the menu width doesn't change https://www.ecocustomboxes.com